# GAS Google Script - How copy value and paste in another Cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need any need with Google script.
I need copy value in the activate cell and paste in another cell.

In this moment my code is:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  

      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
      var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
      var valueCell = cell.getValue();
      console.log(valueCell);

  }
```

I need to monitor the event, get the value and copy it to another column. (column B -> D; and column C -> E). This copy will be made cell by cell and not by cell range. Example: entered value in cell B5, copy to D5. Value entered in C5 I immediately copy to E5, successively.

[image: example]

Comment: you wrapped this in onEdit but it doesn't seem like you'd want to do that. Are you trying to copy one value to another cell whenever someone types something into it? Is there some more restricted way to do that? like only when they do the last line or last column or only when they hit a button?

Comment: @JasonTorpy Exactly! I used the onEdit function but ended up not taking advantage of the function's event! I need to get it dynamically, because the values ​​will be inserted by a Chat Bot.

I need to monitor the event, get the value and copy it to another column. (column B -> D; and column C -> E).

This copy will be made cell by cell and not by cell range.

Example: entered value in cell B5, copy to D5. Value entered in C5 I immediately copy to E5, successively. [link] https://prnt.sc/vynosr

Comment: @LucianoGT if that's the case, you might consider sending updates once an hour or something. grab the origin and dump it into the destination all at once periodically rather than trying to trigger each cell change real time. That will greatly improve the quality if your code. You could also add an onOpen trigger as well or a manual button if you're worried hourly might not always be frequent enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

Your goal is to copy the values from `B->D` and `C->E` when `B` or `C` are edited.

- You need to take full advantage of the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).
- The following script will check whether the name sheet that was edited is `dados`. Then it will ensure that the edit was made **after** row `1` assuming you have headers. Finally, we only accept edits for columns `B` and `C` or column indexes `2` or `3`:

  `if(sh.getName() == 'dados' && row > 1 && [2,3].includes(col))`
- Then we use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator#:%7E:text=The%20conditional%20(ternary)%20operator%20is,if%20the%20condition%20is%20falsy.) to make the code more efficient:
  `sh.getRange(row,col+2).setValue(e.value);`

### Solution:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const ss = e.source;
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  
  if(sh.getName() == 'dados' && row > 1 && [2,3].includes(col)){
   sh.getRange(row,col+2).setValue(e.value);
  }
 }
```

**Note:**

To use this script, **copy** & **paste** the above code in a blank script in **Tools => Script editor**. Save the changes and then you automatically have the desired functionality in the sheet. You **should not** execute the function manually since it is a triggered function.

Comment: Thanks for the help Marios.

The values ​​in the cells will be entered by a Chat Bot! Then my cells will be populated dynamically!

My idea is to place the event function so that the new inclusion of data in a cell is always detected.

These data that will be inserted will be copied to other columns (I attached the image as it can help to understand [link] (https://prnt.sc/vynosr) )

Will I need a loop to do this? I'm confused!

Comment: Hi Mario ...
Thank you for your help! I ran your code and it didn't work! Did not copy the fields to C and E.

Shouldn't I use copyTo () or moveTo () in the code?

It may be that the onEdit function does not detect imput of values, perhaps the onChange () function is better

I don't know ... I'm here breaking my head! LOL

What do you think went wrong?

Comment: @LucianoGT how did you 'run' it? You are not supposed to execute manually this function. If you read my answer I explain in the last paragraph how you can use it. Simply save it to a Google script and then edit the relevant cells in the sheet. Be careful with the sheet name. It has to be dados.

Comment: Hi Marios ...
Thank you very much for your help, however, onEdit () is not able to detect the data that arrives via Chat Bot! The data is added to the spreadsheet via Chat Bot, however, the function, I don't know why, is not detecting the filling that arrives through the api via Chat Bot!

I realized that after the data is in the respective cells, if I click on one of them and change it manually, its algorithm detects and makes the copy to the defined cell.

Comment: I'm finding that the onEdit function does not work when this data comes through an API, that is, when it comes through the API and the cell is filled, the onEdit function does not recognize this as editing, that is, the data is inserted in the spreadsheet and the GS function does not detect it as editing.

So I am thinking of testing onChange, to see if it detects that change.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below, this will work for you as long as it is a specific cell you wish to copy to:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var val = e.value;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var copyTo = sh.getRange('A1').setValue(val); //<<<change the A1 to the cell you wish to copy to
}
}
```

Comment: This is not the recommended way to use an onEdit trigger.